# Page Slide in From Left

Tags: jquery

im trying to extract the `slide in from left` effect that if shown in [this](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/windows8-animations/) demo, and I dont know whats wrong but it does not work at all.

CSS:

```
.slidePageInFromLeft {
  -webkit-animation: slidePageInFromLeft .8s cubic-bezier(.01,1,.22,.99) 1 0.25s normal forwards;
  -o-animation: slidePageInFromLeft .8s cubic-bezier(.01,1,.22,.99) 1 0.25s normal forwards;
  animation: slidePageInFromLeft .8s cubic-bezier(.01,1,.22,.99) 1 0.25s normal forwards
}
@keyframes slidePageInFromLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }

  30% {
    opacity: 1
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slidePageInFromLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }

  30% {
    opacity: 1
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0
  }
}
@-o-keyframes slidePageInFromLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }

  30% {
    opacity: 1
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0
  }
}
```

JS:

```
$('.tile').each(function(){
    var $this= $(this),
        pageType = $this.data('page-type'),
        page = $this.data('page-name');

    $this.on('click',function(){
      if(pageType === "s-page"){
          $('.'+page).addClass('slidePageInFromLeft').removeClass('slidePageBackLeft');
        }
    });
  });

$('.s-close-button').click(function(){
      $(this).parent().removeClass('slidePageInFromLeft').addClass('slidePageBackLeft');
  });
```

i did a jfiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/x68HL/

i wanted to achieve is that a separate page will appear on click of my menu in the `<li>`, probably 50% of the page width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just attribute troubles (data-page-name is not in the html) , and the way to get the attributes on js ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/x68HL/2/

```
<!--html -->
    data-page-type="s-page" data-page-type="random-restored-page" must be
    data-page-type="s-page" data-page-name="random-restored-page"
    //js
$this.attr('data-page-type')
```